# HTTP ERROR 500 for New Mailing after SendGrid SMTP Relay setup

Tags: mailing, smtp

I've set up SendGrid in order to better understand issues we are having with our newsletters. In the Settings -Outbound Mail, I am able to Save and Send Email. However, when I go to Mailing > New Mailing, I get: This page isn’t working www.oursitename.org is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Answer (score 1):

More often than not, I find 500 errors to be server errors where I need my host's help with it. It could be that a php setting is not high enough, such as memory allocated or execution time on a script. I also get it when I am running into a security issue on the server. Usually tech support has me try the process while they are working with me so they can see the server logs in real time. They just need your IP address first so that they can follow along.

What CMS are you using? If it's Drupal, I can tell you real quick how to find your PHP settings. Not sure if it is in the same place in the other systems.

Comment: yes, I'm using drupal. I've put in a ticket with hosting, but that was friday

Comment: Go to the admin area >> Reports >> Status Report. Scroll down until you see something like this: PHP 5.6.32 (more information). Click on the "more information". This will show you the PHP settings. If you could screenshot it or something and paste the details, that will help me see if I can find anything there. Many hosts don't allocate enough resources to properly run CiviCRM. It's why I bought a huge chunk of a server where I can choose memory and all that and then parse it out for all my sites.

Comment: the url for more information is /admin/reports/status/php, but when I click on more information, I am redirected back to status reports.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if the host has it locked down where you can't view that information. I've never had an issue viewing it. The problem may indeed be your host, then. Is it shared hosting? Many shared hosting plans are not suitable for CiviCRM because of the resources it needs to be able to use. Could you point me to a page on your host's site about your plan?